# Install Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have checked available versions using `sudo apt-cache madison ^apache2` but only 2.4.x versions are available.

I want to do and get this done by Anything from adding new repos etc. 
I need apache 2.2 for testing some issues, So can not go with Apache 2.4.

Comment: Why not install 2.4? It contains substantial improvements over 2.2.

Comment: I need apache 2.2 for testing some issues, So can not go with Apache 2.4.

Comment: @f_puras this is also useful for testing apache module support for 2.2, as I'm running into this issue right now.

Comment: @Brian Just been curious - sometimes people have irrational reasons for stickling to obsolete stuff, or are not aware of newer versions.

Comment: @f_puras yes, that is true lol. I wasn't trying to be hostile or anything, just informative.

Comment: @f_puras this is old, but yes I had reasons for this (and yes I knew there were new versions). We have many versions of the software that we create and people who run them might be running them on old versions of ubuntu and old versions of apache, so this piece of software was locked at 2.2 for reasons along these lines